# Is there a way to generate UI in api gateway for all entities or the complete jdl file defined in other microservices collectivelly

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, jhipster

I have one microservice let' say `queueServer` and api-gateway `applicationManager` generated using jhipster.

And I have created one jdl file in `queueServer` using jdl studio and generated the server side entities using `yo jhipster:import-jdl jdl-file`.

But this jdl file have many entities and some of them have relationships with each other, let' say Queue have a one-to-many relationship with appointment.

So is there a way to generate UI for these entities in api-gateway in one go.

Because when I try to generate it using single-single entity I receive errors.

While generating Ui for `Queue` entity using `yo jhipster:entity Queue` in   `applicationManager` I receive the error `Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 7.x` while I am running on nodejs 7.6 and I have tried to execute `npm rebuild node-sass` but still get same error

Complete logs

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/app/entities/queue/queue.model.ts:1:29 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../appointment'.
```

And after it when I try to generate UI for `Appointment` entity I receive

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-51/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:179:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:268:15)
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss 4:14-194

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.scss
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-51/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:179:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:268:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:142:10)
    at factoryCallback (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:325:11)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:251:4
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:93:13
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.scss 2:21-147
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/home/index.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.scss
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-51/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:179:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:268:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:142:10)
    at factoryCallback (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:325:11)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:251:4
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:93:13
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.scss 2:21-155
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/index.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/profiles/page-ribbon.scss
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-51/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:179:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:268:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:142:10)
    at factoryCallback (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:325:11)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:251:4
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:93:13
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/profiles/page-ribbon.scss 2:21-160
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/profiles/page-ribbon.component.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/index.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/app/account/password/password-strength-bar.scss
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-51/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:179:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:268:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:142:10)
    at factoryCallback (/home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:325:11)
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:251:4
    at /home/local/EZDI/naresh.j/git/artiscien/universal-health-care/applicationManager/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:93:13
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/account/password/password-strength-bar.scss 2:21-170
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/account/password/password-strength-bar.component.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/account/index.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/account/account.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
```

Comment: You should not use Node 7.x, we supoport only LTS versions of Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about entity generation in gateway but the problem you reported is about your node environment, downgrade node to LTS version..

Copy your entity definitions from `.jhipster` folder of your microservices to `.jhispter` folder of your gateway and then re-generate your gateway using `yo jhipster --with-entities`